# touchpad behavior with click and hold

Tags: 14.04, trackpad

After updating my relese 14.04, I have observed a modification in the behavior of the tap and hold feature. Before I was able to do this (if I wanted to select a large area of text for example): 
- tap and hold the trackpad and drag my finger across - select a first portion of the text
- relese, move my finger to the other end of the trackpad and tap again - the selection would continue from where it was when I released and it would behave as if I hadn't release at all

This feature is really useful if you want to tap and hold for a long distance and the size of the trackpad along with the pointer speed you selected inhibit you to do so.

I don't know how this feature is called or what to search so I posted my question here.